# Obtain location using service(background) and update gui at regular intervals

Tags: android

I am trying to run a service in the background. Where location is obtained at regular interval and the activity text views are updated whether the app is in E background or foreground. Any pointers or tutorials you guys aware of the? Maybe working examples? I searched a lot and couldn't find something concrete

Thank you

Note: Battery consumption is not an issue for this app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a small blog post about Android location services that should help. It's not service based but it will provide you live location updates in the activity whilst running. Once your activity is paused there is little point in the service providing updates any way and it will hammer your battery as @aehs29 mentioned.

Example code in the blog too: http://www.scotthelme.co.uk/blog/android-location-services/

Comment: The main point behind my question is to run it in the background (not while the activity is running)

Comment: You can adapt that activity to run as a service. Can I ask why it needs to run as a service? Is it some kind of GPS tracker app that needs to run in the background? I only ask because there may be a better way of tackling the problem.

Comment: The app is supposed to get GPS coordinates every second and write it to a file. It has to write something to a file every second even if the coordinated didn't change. This needs to be done whether the app is in background or foreground. Ideas ?:)

Comment: Then these should do the job:

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7KTCCLij
http://pastebin.com/ZcbU1nAg
http://pastebin.com/3gv3biqf

Comment: There are also some permissions and an intent you need to register in the manifest: http://pastebin.com/qBUU9EMP

Comment: Great this looks like what I want. But where is the timer part :)

Comment: Take a look in the service (MainActivity.java) for Thread.sleep(60000); My tracker sends results to a web server, hence the name, and once it was done it waits 60 seconds before it starts over. Change the time 1000 if you want it to be every second.

Comment: No probs, best of luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation would be not to run location services like that, battery consumption would be a really bad issue, to get the location on regular intervals you can either use the Alarm Manager or TimerTask depending on what fits your needs, sorry I cant be more specific but I'm on my phone, hope it helps though.

Comment: I dont think that answers my question. I need it as background service. I am not worried about battery consumption

Comment: Well the answer remains the same, use an IntentService that fetches your location and call it using an Alarm Manager or a Timer Task depending on your needs